Relation between OEIS-A014963 and OEIS-A025476
If to remove all 1's and first appeared numbers (those that do not occur before in the sequence) from A014963, the resulting sequence is A025476 - or at least seems to be. This holds true up to at least first 100000 elements of A014963 (verified numerically, resulting in first 108 numbers in A025476). Why is that?

Please don't use links which might be unreliable and just described the content.

But OEIS is a well-established platform?

As I read the definitions given for those two sequences, they are two ways of saying the same thing (other than the $1$s)
